# How can any proof system be non-sound?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I've not posted on the Mathematics stack exchange before (to my memory) so please excuse me if this is a dull question.

My second-year computer science module for Artificial Intelligence has a subtopic on Knowledge Representation and Reasoning. We've gone over some very basic first-order logic stuff that we did last year in a similar logic-related module, but we've also gone over proof systems. Two of the properties in particular being a proof system's completeness and a proof system's soundness.

I understand completeness: 'A proof system is, with regards to formal semantics, complete if every argument which is valid according to the semantics is also provable using the proof system' - to me, as I understand it, you can clearly have proof systems which aren't complete; some valid arguments may not have a corresponding proof (or perhaps a corresponding proof exists that has yet to be found, so its completeness is non-determinable).

I do not quite understand soundness: 'A proof system is, with regards to formal semantics, sound if every argument which is provable with the proof system is also valid according to semantics'. How can a proof system ever be non-sound? If you take any provable argument, surely it follows that if it is provable, it is valid? Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what it means for an argument to be 'provable', but I took $$\phi_1, \phi_2, ..., \phi_n \vdash_S \psi$$ (for premises $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$, proof system $S$, and conclusion $\psi$) to mean that there exists a sequence of inferences for which $\psi$ follows from $\phi_1,...,\phi_n$.

Am I completely misunderstanding this?

Thank you for any responses :)

Comment: You can define your proof system to be anything you like. For example, $\psi, \phi \to \psi \vdash \phi$ is a perfectly admissible formal rule. It's just that it's not sound with respect to the standard semantics of classical logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a formal proof system $S$ that contains exactly one inference rule:

**Hokus Ponens**

$\therefore \phi$

(in other words, from nothing at all, infer anything you want)

Clearly, with this rule, you can derive ('prove') statements that are not logically valid. For example, we would have $\vdash_S P$ (we can derive atomic statement $P$) but we don't have $\vDash P$ ($P$ is not a logical truth according to formal semantics). So this system is not sound.

Comment: Thank you! What a brilliant example. This makes sense to me now.

Comment: @RWN You’re welcome! Too bad no system we actually ever use has Hokus Ponens… otherwise we could ‘prove’ *everything* in just one step :)